# Flattening hash into string unless value is true

Tags: ruby, string, hash, string-formatting, map-function

I'd need to convert keys and values in a into a string. Sometimes, the values are `true`, and in such cases, the value shouldn't be printed, only the key should be.

E.g.

```
opts = {
    "fail_timeout" => "8s",
    "slow_start" => "130s",
    "resolve" => true
}
```

I did it this way:

```
opts_string = opts.map{|k,v| "#{k}"+ (v.is_a?(TrueClass) ? "" : "=#{v}") }.join(' ')
# => "fail_timeout=8s slow_start=130s resolve"
```

Is there an easier way?

Comment: What is the problem with your solution? `opts.map { |k,v| true == v ? k : "#{k}=#{v}" }.join(' ')` simplifies the true evaluation.

Comment: I think you are good with it... (y) other solutions will be just variations not necessarily better

Comment: @sschmeck - that's a great solution, and the one I'm going with :) And the only issue that I had with my solution was, that it looked so long and clumsy.

Comment: Are the values either strings or `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `v == true`

```
opts.map { |k,v| v == true ? k : "#{k}=#{v}" }.join(' ')     
#=> "fail_timeout=8s slow_start=130s resolve"
```

Comment: I prefer this to my `inject` answer. No `memo` needed.

Comment: why `flat_map` instead of `map`?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon error on my part; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Should be noted sschmeck had this answer in the comments before me whereas I originally and independently used `flat_map` until Md.FarhanMemon pointed out the refactor. Credit to both, as such this answer has been made a community wiki.

Comment: @iceツ Thanks a lot to you as well ☺

Comment: on a side note (and an extremely minor one given the context) @sschmeck's comment is actually slightly more performant. It seems there is less overhead using `true` as the receiver rather than the argument. https://repl.it/JHXF

Comment: @engineersmnky `TrueClass#==` is inherited from `BasicObject`, it merely checks for object identity, whereas `String#==` involves some type checks.

Comment: @engineersmnky Interesting. Can somebody explain, why the solution from sschmeck is faster, than the one from iceツ?

Answer (score 1):

```
opts.map{|k, v| v == true ? [k] : [k, v]}
    .map{|tuple| tuple.join('=')}
    .join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
opts.inject("") { |memo, (k,v)| memo << (v == true ? k : [k,v].join("=")) + " " }.strip
```

Not sure this is really any better than what you have, except the equality check could be `== true` instead of `is_a?`.

Comment: it doesn't give the expected output